# How are the elements inside the navbar centered vertically in Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I was taking a look at the navbar element in Twitter Bootstrap to see how they vertically center the elements inside the navbar because that is something I am always struggling with.

I always have to resort to 'random' margin/padding values which I've been told aren't good because they are magic numbers that only work in that specific context.

Surprisingly I was not able to discovery anything that actually vertical centers the elements – no `line-height` trickery or anything really, no `display: table-cell`.
The `.navbar-brand` class has a `line-height` of `20px` (like the links inside `.navbar-nav`) and a `padding` of `15px`, but how does that center anything? How do they do that?

Here you can see the code of the navbar: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Please link to example

Comment: Which navbar are you looking at? It looks like it has both top and bottom padding - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less#L249

Comment: @Sébastien I added a link, please see my edit.

Comment: @Wex I am looking at the navbar I just linked. The funny thing is, Firebug does not show any padding, strange.

Answer (score 1):

The navbar uses top and bottom padding to vertically center the text:

```css
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

They don't vertically center the text.

I tested this by adding text to a navbar element using inspect:element in Chrome. Then I forced width the same way. The text wrapped to the next line. All lines were lined up at the top, not centered.